# Can't push to one github repo because it keeps trying from the username of my other repo

Tags: github, pycharm

I have 2 separate github accounts.  I'm using PyCharm for a project and am trying to push to the repo and am getting a 403 error that says

> remote: Permission to (repo) denied to (username of my other account)

I had logged out of my other account, I logged out of google incase it was picking up on that somehow, in the terminal I ran

> git config –global –unset user.name "(my github username)"

> git config –global –unset user.email "(the email associated with my github account)"

Then I ran

> git config –global user.name "(username of other account)"

> git config –global user.email "(email associated with the other account)"

Then I tried pushing again and it still didn't work.  After doing a little research I saw examples showing people were using their first and last name in the `user.name` command so I tried the same steps over and it still didn't work.

A while back I installed gitbash on my computer and used it in VSCode and I'm wondering if maybe that has something to do with it.  I had even tried running the commands from powershell and got the same results  Any suggestions?